# How to open playlist as XML file in Python 3 as dict.?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open a playlist(exported from iTunes as XML file) in Python as a dictionary. I tried this:

```
import plistlib

plist = plistlib.readPlist(fileName)
print(plist)
```

it prints me a dictionary, but with this message:

```
DeprecationWarning: The readPlist function is deprecated, use load() instead
```

Answer (score 0):

The readPlist function has been deprecated so just use the load function that does the same

```py
import plistlib
fp = open(filename, "rb")
plist = plistlib.load(fp)
print(plist)
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html#plistlib.load):

> plistlib.load(fp, *, fmt=None, use_builtin_types=True, dict_type=dict)
>
> Read a plist file. fp should be a readable and binary file object.
>   Return the unpacked root object (which usually is a dictionary).

Comment: This shoud be added:  fp = open(filename, "rb")  then call plistlib.load(filename).